# Accessing a PHP static variables across multiple class files

Tags: php

I have a PHP class file A with a static variable, I have one class file B that uses that class A and instantiates its static variable. i wish to access Class A's ststic varibale from another class C in another file. How do i do this. I tried this.I know of the singleton structure but am not sure it applies to this. take a look below of what am trying to achieve. Please not i do not wish to use sessions.

> classA.php

```
  <?php
   Class A{
  public static $foo = array ();
 public static function doSomething(){
   //... Do some process and instantiate static vairable $face
   self::$foo = outputofsomeprocess();
 }
}
?>
```

> classB.php

```
<?php
require_once "classA.php";
class B{
public function dosomethingelse(){
    A::doSomething();
}
}
?>
```

> classC.php

```
<?php
require_once "classA.php";
 class C{
    public function dosomethingelse(){
    echo A::$foo[0];
   }
  }
?>
```

I get null from the echo in class C

Comment: `A::doSomething();` not `classA::doSomething();` You reference the actual class name, not the file that it's defined in

Comment: that was a mistake i have corrected it now.

Comment: maybe you're looking for extends

Comment: @donald123 are you saying I extend A on C? please explain futher

Comment: How you initialize Class C? If you need to do A::doSomething() executed in class B then you need to extend class B instead A::foo[0] is null, because it is not set

Comment: [Demo](http://3v4l.org/EDJTl)

Comment: @MarkBaker I don't think that demo is valid. Why? Because it's on the same file am talking about 3 classes in 3 separate files. Besides I think the only valid solution is to some how transit the instance of classA to classC without using the require_once "classA.php"

Comment: It shouldn't matter whether the classes are defined in different files or not, as long as they're being properly included (and you'd get errors if they weren't).... but singletons or sessions have nothing to do with this

Comment: @MarkBaker please make the demo an answer in this question so I can comment in my findings as I test your solution. Thanks.

Comment: You don't have any instance of class A, you're only accessing it statically so you don't need any instance

Comment: But your files all need to have been included, whether using individual include/require or using an autoloader

Comment: @MarkBaker works like a charm! Implemented your demo! Thanks a billion. you could put it here so i up vote and accept it as an answer. thank again.

Answer (score 0):

Coming from a C# background, it's a bit different but that should do the trick.

```
class A1 {

    public static $foo = array();

}


<?php
require_once 'classA.php';

class B2 {

    public static function doSomethings() {

       var_dump(A1::$foo);
    }
}

B2::doSomethings();
```